# How can I pass a key,value pair from a function argument through to another function?

Tags: python

Contrived example:

```
from otherplace import enhance_thing

def modify_thing(mult=False, add=False, sub=False):
    arguments = locals()
    thing = 1
    for key,value in arguments.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        thing = enhance_thing(thing, key=value)
    return thing
```

Firstly if you're not familiar `arguments` will become a dictionary of the input keyword arguments, the default being `{"mult": False, "add": False, "sub": False}`

Now I would expect `modify_thing(add=3, mult=5)` function to call `enhance_thing` 2 times, firstly as `enhance_thing(1, add=3)` then as `enhance_thing(4, mult=5)` and to finally `return 20`.

However it will only ever call `enhance_thing(1, key=3)` and then return an error. How do I change the keyword `key` into my actual variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass keyword arguments directly through, it's best to use `kwargs` to capture all of the keyword arguments and then you can pass them one at a time:

```
from otherplace import enhance_thing

def modify_thing(**kwargs):
    thing = 1
    # kwargs will become a dict of {'add': 3, 'mult': 5} in your example
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        # **{key: value} will produce the dynamic `key=value` syntax you want where key and value are replaced by the actual keyword arguments
        # in your example, it will create enhance_thing(thing, add=3) and then enhance_thing(thing, mult=5)
        thing = enhance_thing(thing, **{key: value}) # this will pass the individual keyword arguments through
    return thing
```

Comment: Thanks, it was just a case of amending `thing = enhance_thing(thing, key=value)` to `thing = enhance_thing(thing, **{key: value})`. Unfortunately I couldn't use `**kwargs` in the outer function due to the way I am using a certain library, but this certainly worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris ah I see. No problem, glad the other part worked for you

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that locals() contain a lot of variables, not just the ones you received in modify_thing as arguments.

A probable solution might be:

```
from otherplace import enhance_thing

def modify_thing(mult=False, add=False, sub=False):
    arguments = {"mult": mult, "add": add, "sub": sub}
    thing = 1
    for key,value in arguments.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        thing = enhance_thing(thing, key=value)
    return thing
```

But it causes code duplication. Maybe it's better to use the following solution:

```
from otherplace import enhance_thing

def modify_thing(**kwargs):
    arguments = kwargs
    # Maybe some assertation about what kwargs contains
    thing = 1
    for key,value in arguments.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        thing = enhance_thing(thing, key=value)
    return thing
```

Also, the "thing" variable is not accumulating. So I guess you meant to use += insteed of =.

To summarize:

```
from otherplace import enhance_thing

def modify_thing(**kwargs):
    arguments = kwargs
    # Maybe some assertation about what kwargs contains
    thing = 1
    for key,value in arguments.items():
        if not value:
            continue
        thing += enhance_thing(thing, key=value)
    return thing
```

Good luck!

Comment: This does not solve the issue that OP had where `key` will be interpreted as the keyword argument name, rather than creating a dynamic argument according to the original keyword arguments